# Adding jQuery support in Eclipse EE 2019-03

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse

*Several questions similar to this were asked, but many years ago, and the links provided in those questions are dead.*

I have installed Eclipse EE,version 2019-03 a week ago (I worked on IntelliJ Ultimate until my subscription ran out), and I can not seem to find a decent answer on how to install **jQuery auto-complete** on eclipse.

Searching the Eclipse Marketplace with the keyword "jQuery" returned 0 results for me.

Please share your knowledge with me and the world,as to how can someone add jQuery support on eclipse.

Comment: If [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-wild-web-developer-html-css-javascript-typescript-json-yaml-xml-nodejs) does not support iQuery, use the [Tern Eclipse IDE](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tern-eclipse-ide). [Searching the Eclipse Marketplace for "jQuery" returns 9 results for me](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/jquery).

Comment: I also had the same question. Many people suggested to use JSDT plugin but it gives 404 error. After some searching, I have enabled jQuery tern plugins but it didn't solve the issue.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVR08.png